# Incremental table names

Tags: sql-server, select

I'm currently trying to find some information with a query that will automatically update on a website every 24 hours - this involves a number of columns in a daily backup table that I need to pull information from.

The problem I have is the query has to specifically state the database table, which makes the query rather static - and I need something a bit more dynamic.

I have a daily backup table with the naming system as follows:

```
daily_backup_130328 
daily_backup_130329 
daily_backup_130330 
daily_backup_130331 
daily_backup_130401 
daily_backup_130402
```

So when I state my FROM table, I name one of these - usually the latest one available (so `"daily_backup_0402"` from the example list). Currently the only way I can get this to update is to manually go in and update the query every day before the scheduled run.

My question is: is there a way that I can get it to select the latest "daily_backup_??????" table automatically?

Edit: I'm on about bog standard queries like "SELECT * FROM daily_backup_130402" ORDER BY CheeseType ASC;

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: What database software, what website software, what programming language?

Comment: MSSQL + Heidi, mix of js and html

Comment: What is a "*bog standard query*"?

Answer (score 0):

A generic answer: you could implement a daily_backup SP.

Then, for a specified server/driver, there should be specific catalog and dynamic query facilities.

There are chances that the SW that fills daily_backup_NNNNNN could also update the stored procedure, then relieving you at all from the manual burden. Again, that could be done dynamically, depending on server details (triggers on metadata).